# Show that the method of moments estimator of $\theta$ is biased

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, parameter-estimation

Let ${X_1},...,{X_n}$  a random sample from the probability distribution with pdf $f(x) = \theta {x^{\theta  - 1}}$, $0 < x < 1$ where $\theta  > 0$

I've found the method of moments estimator for $\theta$ to be : ${\hat \theta _{mom}} = \frac{{\overline X }}{{1 - \overline X }}$

Next, I'm asked to show that ${\hat \theta _{mom}}$ is biased if $n=1$ and $\theta=1$. I'm struggling to understand the solution provided, which follows:
If $n=1$ and $\theta=1$ then $f(x)=1$ and $X_1=\overline X$

$$E[{\hat \theta _{mom}}] = E\left[ {\frac{{{X_1}}}{{{X_1} + 1}}} \right] = 1 - E\left[ {\frac{1}{{{X_1} + 1}}} \right] = 1 - \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{1}{{1 - x}}dx =  - \infty  \ne \theta }$$

I understand why a result of $- \infty $ not being equal to theta proves it is biased, however I don't understand how the expectations and the integral have been formulated.

If ${\hat \theta _{mom}} = \frac{{\overline X }}{{1 - \overline X }}$ then why is $E[{\hat \theta _{mom}}]$ not equivalent with $E\left[ {\frac{{{X_1}}}{{1 - {X_1}}}} \right]$? And how is the expectation equivalent with the integral?

I hope somebody can shed some light on what it is that I'm missing here.

Comment: How can the expected value a positive random variable $\frac{\bar{X}}{1-\bar{X}}$ equal$-\infty$? The solution you wrote is not correct.

If $\theta=n=1$ then $\bar{X}=X_1 \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ so $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere. Hence $$\mathbb{E}\Bigg(\frac{\bar{X}}{1-\bar{X}}\Bigg)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{1-x}\Big)f(x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{xdx}{1-x}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 typos in the solution from your question.

$\theta_{mom} \ne {\frac{{{X_1}}}{{{X_1} + 1}}} $ because $\theta_{mom} = \frac{X_1}{1-X_1}$.

And if we will work with $\theta^* =  {\frac{{{X_1}}}{{{X_1} + 1}}} $, then instead of

$$E \theta^* = E\left[ {\frac{{{X_1}}}{{{X_1} + 1}}} \right] = 1 - E\left[ {\frac{1}{{{X_1} + 1}}} \right] = 1 - \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{1}{{1 - x}}dx }$$
we should have
$$1 - \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{1}{{1 + x}}dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

With a different approach it is easy to show that the result is valid in general,  $\forall n, \theta$

Observe that you are not asked to explicitly calculate $E(\hat{\theta}_{MM})$ but only to show that it is not $\theta$

Your estimator is

$$\hat{\theta}_{MM}= \frac{\overline{X}_n}{1-  \overline{X}_n  }$$

Thus, using Jensen's inequality you get

$$E(\hat{\theta}_{MM})\ne  \frac{E(\overline{X}_n)}{1-E(\overline{X}_n)  }=\frac{E(X)}{1-E(X)}=\frac{\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}}{1- \frac{\theta}{\theta+1}}  =\theta$$

and you are all set!

---

On the other hand, as sample mean is consistent for $E(X)=\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$ and $g(z)=\frac{z}{1-z}$ is continuous in $z$, then $\hat{\theta}_{MM}$ is consistent for $\theta$